# Unbound not resolving some domain regions

Tags: pihole, unbound

My RaspberryPi with PiHole and Unbound worked for years but since around 2 weeks ago some domain regions are not being resolved consistently. Domains ending on .ar, .co and .mx are not getting resolved while domains like .cl are never a problem. I could not find an issue with any other domain region. 
 Config checks out without any errors and the logs also show nothing out of the ordinary. Also stopping the service and restarting it sometimes solves the issue but not always for all domain regions (.mx will most likely work after a restart of the service but .co will still be broken). A restart of the rPi itself solves the issue for a while.
Just waiting and asking for a resolve of a domain also helps. After 10-15 minutes it will most likely resolve the domain.

Has anyone an idea what the problem could be?